# $.fancybox.close() not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, undefined

I know that question was discussed plenty of times, but i tried all suggestions and noone didn't work. I am using fancybox with href atribute where content is loading using ajax.

```
$('a').fancybox(
        {
            href:'ajax/test.php',
            titleShow:false
        });
```

And in content i had custom close button

```
<a href="javascript:void(1)" title="close" onclick="$.fancybox.close()">Pirkti prekes</a>
```

And when i click that i got $.fancybox is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a onclick it should look like

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $(this).fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the fancybox, but your href attribute should just be a '#' with a 'return false' at the end of your onclick handler.

Comment: thanks for replies, but no one suggestion didn't work. So i realize to the custom close button put refresh to the same page.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is because you're loading the ajax content into an iframe?

Try

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
```

Also, the following works for me as well when using the same selector that was used to initialize fancybox in my page header script.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('a.myclass').fancybox.close();">Close</a>
```

Where a.myclass was used as the selector for the fancybox as follows

```
$("a.myclass").fancybox({
  'frameWidth':  920,
  'frameHeight':  705 //with whatever other attributes you want to define
});
```

EDIT: See the Fancybox Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/a6eaf87875b93829

Answer (score 2):

sometimes i have the same problem, and use:

```
parent.$('body').fancybox.close();
```

or

```
$('body').fancybox.close();
```

or

```
 $.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: TypeError: $.fancybox is undefined , TypeError: $(...).fancybox is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I use below code. It works generally

```
$('.fancybox-close').click();
```